# ¿Cómo eliminar el piecewise de un output?

Tags: python

Tengo este código para calcular la transformada de laplace de una función, y lo comparo con el laplace_transform de sympy.

```
from sympy import integrate,Symbol,oo,cos
from sympy.abc import x,s
from sympy.integrals import laplace_transform

def laplace(fx):
    Lfx=integrate((exp(-s*x))*(fx),(x,0,oo))
    return Lfx

print (laplace(cos(3*x)))
fx1=cos(3*x)
print (laplace_transform(fx1,x,s))
```

El output es

```
Piecewise((s/(9*(s**2/9 + 1)), Abs(periodic_argument(polar_lift(s)**2, oo)) < pi), (Integral(exp(-s*x)*cos(3*x), (x, 0, oo)), True))
(s/(s**2 + 9), 0, True)
```

Quiero que ambas respuestas estén expresadas igual (en este caso s/(s**2 + 9)) y que no aparezca el piecewise. Sé que las condiciones que aparecen después las puedo eliminar con un conds='None', pero no sé como hacer que las respuestas sean iguales. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Con `Lfx=integrate((exp(-s*x))*(fx),(x,0,oo), conds='none')` evitamos que retorne una instancia Piecewise porque ignora las condiciones de convergencia. Esto nos retorna `s/(9*(s**2/9 + 1))` simplemente. El tema de que aparezca el resultado con la misma expresión matemática que con  `laplace_transform` no se si será posible, eso depende de la implementación de ambos módulos.